# Does a sidebar like Google Desktop sidebar exist for Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation

Does a sidebar like Google Desktop sidebar exist for Ubuntu? I want to see commodity prices, stock tickers, CPU performance, etc. out of the corner of my eye. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so, however there is something called Conky which can display CPU information and more.

You can install it by running the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install conky conky-all
```

Or install it the Ubuntu Software Center, by searching for `conky`.

The problem however is that you still need to configure Conky by yourself which can be tricky, the best thing to do that is by using the program called Conky Manager or visit the website of conky. http://www.webupd8.org/2013/07/conky-manager-gui-for-managing-conky.html
http://conky.sourceforge.net/

Personally I don't use conky but I hope this helps a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You might find this of interest.

http://code.google.com/p/google-gadgets-for-linux/